# Page Viewer Web Part acting up

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, page-viewer-web-part

I added a page viewer web part to one of my site pages. However, it was behaving in a strange way. When you would go to the site page, it would show you it for a short moment, then it would take you to the actual URL of what you put in the page viewer. I deleted the web part from the page. You can't see it on the page now, but it's behaving as if it is still there. It keeps rerouting me to the URL of what I wanted in the page viewer.

Comment: Use ?contents=1 and delete the web part.

Comment: not sure what you mean by ?contents=1

Comment: Appending ?contents=1 to the page you are on currently like so : page.aspx?contents=1 will take you to the web part management page where you can delete or close web parts.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I don't know how I would ever know that. How do I show this question as answered?

Comment: That is how i felt when i learned about  this for the 1st time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Posting comment as answer*
Append ?contents=1 at the end of your page and delete the web part.